# Routing an Email from my server

Tags: linux, postfix

I am a C# programmer and doing an internship as a programmer, where i have to work with *linux*, which I've never done before.

I have installed and configured `postfix` successfully on a Linux server (Debian). My company has some online server (e.g. with IP `11.100.200.250`). And I have checked it by sending email through `telnet`, and it's working fine.

Now my boss wants me, that an email ID, `mailsend@ourcompanydomain.com`. He is using `Outlook`. 
Whenever he sends an email from this address, the email should be routed from the online server (11.100.200.250) on which I have installed and configured `postfix`.

I have searched a lot on Google, but so far I have been unable to find out what exactly I have to do.

Comment: Which Distribution you using ?

Comment: @Babinlonston it says `Debian` in the question (without any version though)

Comment: what is the exact problem? afaiu, you want your outlook client to send emails via a given server for a specific "from" address. if this is the case, you have to configure outlook to use that server (for the given email address). not much you can do on the server side (apart from *accepting* emails for `ourcompanydomain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while i'm not an `outlook` user (hey, this is a unix&linux forum, not w32...), i assume that this is similar to any other decent MUA (e.g. thunderbird):

- create a new "mail *account*" in your MUA
- configure the account to use the *From-address* `<mailsend@ourcompanydomain.com>`
- configure the account to use the *outgoing* mail-server `11.100.200.250`